# Finite Graph With Degree $\geq 2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

Show that a finite graph with all vertices with degree $\geq 2$  has a cycle that contains a vertex which is non-adjacent to any other vertices not contained in the cycle.

I tried to start at an arbitrary ∈ and let  be a maximal path beginning at . and then let  be the endpoint of . then all neighbors of  must be in  because all neighbors of P has degree larger than 2, meaning that maximal path can go around all neighbors  before ending at P. Then somehow i close the loop of this maximal path and have this cycle? How would i do that.

Comment: Unless I'm reading this wrong or missing something, this seems extremely false. An obvious counterexample is a complete graph. Then every vertex of every cycle is adjacent to all other vertices not in the cycle.

Comment: @user145640 So take the cycle going through all the vertices.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Good point!

Answer (score 1):

To close the loop, take the edge from $u$ to its *earliest* neighbor of $P$: the one that is furthest from $u$ and closest to $v$. Then follow $P$ back to $u$. Throw away the portion of $P$ before any of $u$'s neighbors.

Now all the neighbors of $u$ are on this cycle, because all of them were on the path $P$ to begin with - and since we went back to the earliest of them, we'll see all the others when we follow $P$ back to $u$.